# survival analysis in shiny

Tags: shiny, survival-analysis

I met a problem with presenting my survival analysis by `shiny` app. I upload a dataset for my analysis and use 3 selectInputs to determine the time censor and group. However when I want to use for example `input$si5ax` as my time variable, it comes a error that Time variable is not numeric.

the code is as follows:

```
data_set <- reactive({

 infile <- input$dataset3

  if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(NULL)
    }

    infile3 <- input$dataset3
    read.csv(infile3$datapath,sep=',')
  })

aea8 <- eventReactive(input$doa8,{

   fit1 <- survfit(Surv(input$si5ax, censor)~group, data = data_set())

  ggsurv(fit1)+theme_bw(base_size = 16)

})

output$plota1 <- renderPlot({

aea8()  
})
```

This problem will be solved when I use time directly instead of input selection.  The same problem takes place by variable censor and group. The error message said the length of group is not equal. 
I am looking forward for helping

Comment: Will be hard to help without fully reproducible example. What type of input is `input$si5ax` associated with.

Comment: I guess your `input$si5ax` comes in form of `string` (e.g. "xyz", same apply for group, and censor), thus you can't just put it into formula.

Comment: @Vova hello Vova thanks for the hint, I think you are right. I have also tried regression(lm) with input$... . It seems that I must use as.formular and paste to let the shiny recognize my parameters. However, do you know how to achieve this in surv()?

Comment: I wander if `get(input$si5ax)` can help

Comment: @Vova thanks I will try

Comment: Noticing this as a survival analysis question, and that's an area I'm trying to support. I'm not a shiny user s I would need a complete example if this question is still open. I have run shiny examples but only when they have both "sides" of the code presented.

Comment: hey thanks for leaving the message and providing helps. I already found out the solution.

Comment: @wuy would you be kind posting the solution, so other users can see what was relevant in suggestions?

Comment: sure. the idea is as same as in lm function u have to use the paste and as.formular to combine all the segments as a whole expression which could be recognized by R